# Explanation of simple property of space of smooth functions with compact support

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have seen this property used in my text and notes for partial differential equations class, but I can't seem to reconcile how to works. Let $D(\mathbb{R})=C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of smooth function with compact support in $\mathbb{R}$. I have seen it concluded in the text that if $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$, then
$$-\int_0^\infty \phi'(x)dx=\phi(0)$$
I feel like I am missing some basic property, I don't see why this always works for any $\phi \in D(\Omega)$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use that $\int_0^\infty=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b$, $\int_a^b f'=f(b)-f(a)$ and $\phi(b)=0$ for $b$ large enough.

Comment: @Pedro of course after I write the question I look at it and realize if I use integration by parts it seems to work out pretty well. Yes thank you!